# Get instance alias

Tags: sql-server

I have server [Myserver] with instances [I1], [I2], [I3].
They have aliases MyserverI1, MyserverI2, MyserverI3.

I use the aliases when connecting in for example SSMS.
Using @@SERVERNAME returns [Myserver\I1] for MyserverI1.

(How) can I translate aliases like these, for example MyserverI1 to [Myserver\I1] - or the other way around, in TSQL code?

Comment: unless you're talking about something different, aliases are defined on the *client* machine, and have been translated into the real terms before any communication actually happens with the SQL Server service. It has *no* knowledge of what aliases are being used.

Comment: Maybe you're thinking of CNAMES?   Sounds more like a DBA question than a developer question.